# problems with minishowcase

Tags: php, jquery, plugins

I am having problems setting up minishowcase, i keep getting

```
Notice: Undefined variable: lang in /home5/thechrj4/public_html/shisharoom/minishowcase/index.php on line 149
```

the url is [link text](http://shisharoom.jerseygetonline.com/minishowcase/)

If you know how i could fix it, that would be great, if not could you suggest another gallery, that does similar things. The features i am looking for is the ability to have multiple albums based on the directory name. I just want to put folders of images on the site and the albums automatically generate.

Answer (score 0):

Usually notices are not errors. You can switch off them by setting `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE)`.

Comment: just add that code at begining of the main php file of your gallery / blog index.php
there is also another method adding an php.ini file to your site root dir with the following content:
`error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE`